# Share Gif image on facebook in ios

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5, ios7

how to share .gif image in Facebook  from my ios app?
 i have tried png and jpg format it works .
 but when i share .gif file. 
it will just share as normal image **not as an animated image.**
so if anybody had try it. please help me out to find solutions.

Comment: Hello. Do you solved your problem? I have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Source**: [Guide to Animated Gifs for Facebook](http://facebook.about.com/od/Advanced/ss/Guide-To-Animated-Gifs-For-Facebook.htm)

> If you try to upload a GIF to Facebook, a still image of the first
>   frame will appear. However, there are three ways to try and outsmart
>   the system.
>
> - Make a Youtube video look like a GIF.
> - Use a third party app on    Facebook like Animated Picture. For this    app, you do not use your own    files. There are hundreds
>     sorted out    in different categories to    choose from.
> - Post a link to the GIF. Yes, the still image will show    up, but a    description will accompany it. Yes, it may take more time,    but
>     your friends will be curious as to what it entails.
>
> But, if the GIF you want to upload is not a moving picture, it should
>   work just fine. If you have a GIF image that is a nonmoving image, you
>   should have no problem uploading it to Facebook. According to the
>   Facebook Developers page, GIFs are one of many file types allowed for
>   uploading to the platform. Other supported image file types include
>   JPG, PNG, PSD, TIFF, JP2, IFF, WBMP and XBM images.

PS: This was the first result that I got when I googled about it. You'll find plenty of other sources for doing the same. For example: [You Can Finally Put GIFs on Facebook](http://gizmodo.com/you-can-finally-put-gifs-on-facebook-heres-how-1221285918).

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL  URLWithString:@"facebook://app"]]){

    NSLog(@"imag %@",_GIFURL);

    self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;
    self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"com.facebook.photo";
    self.documentationInteractionController = [self setupControllerWithURL:_GIFURL usingDelegate:self];
    [self.documentationInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];

}
else {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"facebook not installed." message:@"Your device has no facebook installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIActivityItemProvider and extend - (id)item {} for Facebook:

Just upload the GIF to Giphy, then provide the Giphy URL to UIActivityViewController instead of the file contents, Facebook will recognize it and show the animated GIF

```
- (id)item
{    
    if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
        // Upload to Giphy
        ...
        return [NSURL URLWithString:giphyURL];
    }
}
```

full code is in my [GitHub](https://github.com/furic/GifItemProvider), I am actually a iOS newb so some experts please correct me and the code if possible