# iOS Share GIF (animated image) not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter, gif

It's been almost 2 days that i'm looking to find a solution to my problem but i wasn't successful ,  i want to share GIF (animated image) on Facebook, Twitter, Email, WhatsApp , using **"UIActivityViewController"**.

This is my code :

```
NSURL *imagePath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sth.gif"];
NSData *animatedGif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imagePath];

NSArray *sharingItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: animatedGif,stringToShare, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
```

When i share in Email its animated and its working perfect , but in Twitter , Facebook , whatsApp Gifs are not animated and its like an image ...
I already read all Stack-overflow questions about the same problem Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749933/share-gif-image-on-facebook-in-ios) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623931/how-to-share-an-gif-animated-images-in-ios) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357099/can-i-tweet-an-animated-gif-from-a-uiactivityviewcontroller-and-the-native-uiact) but its not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far base on days research found out that :

**TWITTER** : For share a GIF on twitter had to use twitter API and create a multipart request to achieve the goal and its working very well.

**FACEBOOK** : I did share some GIF on Facebook using **FACEBOOKSHAREKIT** , but i don't know why sometimes Gifs are animated, sometimes not.

**INSTAGRAM** : To share gif on Instagram had to convert GIFS to MP4 (or any other video formats accepted by Instagram) then save it into camera roll then share it , It is little twisted but its working very well.

**WHATSAPP** : It not supporting GIF at all. **READ THE UPDATE**

To do all of this i couldn't use **"UIActivityViewController"** , so decided to create a custom share page. if anybody know something to add here , to help me and others please tell me (especially about Facebook).
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

**WHATSAPP** : Thanks to @AmmarShahid, as he mentioned in comments, Whatsapp now supports gif.

Comment: whatsapp now supports gif. you only have to pass data in nsdata format.

Comment: @ammarshahid thanks, i have update my answer ... by the time i have written the answer whatsapp does not supported the .gif

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the similar problem and Googled a lot but still not a perfect solution, the best I came up is here:

Use UIActivityItemProvider and extend - (id)item {} for different UIActivityType:

**Twitter**: The default UIActivityViewController Twitter share doesn't support it yet which it will "scale down" it as a still JPG. However somehow it works for GIF less than 100kb (tested in iOS 9) and I don't know why. Therefore, I have to use SLRequest to upload the GIF as taught in [here](http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com.au/2016/01/how-to-using-slrequest-to-upload-image.html?showComment=1460489097793#c638358337669317406). When the SLRequest is done and return, dismiss the UIActivityViewController. The downside of that is no preview share sheet and users cannot type their own message anymore.

**Facebook**: It's actually much easier! Just upload the GIF to Giphy, then provide the Giphy URL to UIActivityViewController instead of the file contents, Facebook will recognize it and show the animated GIF

```
- (id)item
{    
    if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
        // Upload to Giphy
        ...
        return [NSURL URLWithString:giphyURL];
    }
    if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
        // Use SLRequest to share instead
        ...
        // Dismiss the UIActivityViewController (I am using Unity)
        [UnityGetGLViewController() dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion: NULL];
        return nil;
    }
}
```

full code is in my [GitHub](https://github.com/furic/GifItemProvider), I am actually a iOS newb so some experts please correct me and the code if possible

Comment: Your solution for facebook is good, unfortunately up to now this is the only way to share gifs on facebook .

Answer (score 0):

//  Share GIF File: WhatsApp

```
    NSURL *imageUrl =[self.ImageArray objectAtIndex:currentPhotoIndex];
    NSString *path=imageUrl.absoluteString;
    NSArray *strings = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *mygif=[strings objectAtIndex:strings.count-1];

    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MrHRamani"];

    NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:mygif];

    NSURL *urll=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSLog(@"imag %@",imageUrl);
    self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;
    self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    self.documentationInteractionController = [self setupControllerWithURL:urll usingDelegate:self];
    [self.documentationInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```