# iOS Share GIF to ONLY Twitter

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, twitter, gif, uiactivityviewcontroller

I need to give my players an ability to post GIF replays ONLY to their Twitter accounts. I've managed to create a basic general sharing dialog but the problem is, I can't remove all irrelevant sharing options: Notes, Skype and etc. Long hours of fighting with iOS and no results. There are no activity types for the stuff I want to exclude, so adding it to "excludedActivityTypes" is impossible. Tweet Sheet didn't help either, it can't share GIFs.

Are there any other options, guys? Current implementation:

[image: Current implementation]

I want to do smth like this (just add FB to excluded activities):

[image: I want to do smth like this (just add FB to excluded activities)]

Comment: Using this past code fully working condition :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007067/ios-share-gif-animated-image-not-working/44041180#44041180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only wanting to allow sharing of the animated GIF to Twitter, it doesn't make much sense to use the `UIActivityViewController` to display the share sheet with only one option.

Why not just build your own using the `SLComposeViewController`? You have greater control over the UI and it's fewer button presses for the user.  To do so, you can take a look at the sample code provided in [this tutorial](http://www.iosinsight.com/twitter-integration-with-swift/).

Comment: Hey thanks! I'll try this out and mark this question closed if it'll work

Comment: The tutorial you've posted here says "However, currently if you want to include animated GIFs in a tweet, you need to use SLRequest and roll your own UI" I don't know Obj C at all, are there any ways to use  SLComposeViewController and SLRequest together without writing my own UI?

Comment: Ok I've managed to integrate this beauty https://github.com/romaonthego/REComposeViewController, it works ok with iOS 9, so there were no problems with its deprecated state.

Answer (score 0):

// Use this code :by. Ramani Hitesh iOS developer)

```
    NSURL *imageUrl =[self.ImageArray objectAtIndex:currentPhotoIndex];
    NSString *path=imageUrl.absoluteString;
    NSArray *strings = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *mygif=[strings objectAtIndex:strings.count-1];

    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MrHRamani"];

    NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:mygif];

    NSURL *urll=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSLog(@"imag %@",imageUrl);
    self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;
    self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    self.documentationInteractionController = [self setupControllerWithURL:urll usingDelegate:self];
    [self.documentationInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```